# Should NUnit "theory" assumptions include algorithm details

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, theory

Let's say that I would like to change my NUnit parametrized test method to a theory. As far as theories go they should define all assumptions/preconditions under which assertions will pass. As per NUnit documentation:

> *[when comparing theory to parametrized test] A theory, on the other hand, makes a general statement that all of its assertions will pass for all arguments satisfying certain assumptions.*

But as I understand it this means that called PUT's code should be basically translated to assumptions. **Completely**.

What's the point having theories then? Because our algorithm would be written twice. First as testable code and second as theory assumptions. So if we'd intro a bug in the algorithm both our code and test would likely have the same bug. **What's the point then?**

### Example for better understanding

Let's say we're having a checksum method that only supports digits and we'd like to test it using a theory. Let's write a theory:

```
static Regex rx = new Regex(@"^\d+$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

[Theory]
public void ChecksumTheory(string value)
{
    Assume.That(!string.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace(value));
    Assume.That(value.Length > 1); // one single number + checksum = same number twice
    Assume.That(rx.IsMatch(value));

    var cc = new ChecksumValidator();

    bool result = cc.ValidateValue(value);

    Assert.IsTrue(result); // not really as algorithm assumptions are missing
}
```

This is a pretty nice theory, except that without actually implementing the tested code algorithm and expressing it as a set of assumptions its assertions still won't pass because without explicit algorithm assumptions we can't know what the outcome of the validation will be.

### Additional info

Theories seem rather trivial and concise when we only need to provide assumptions on *input state* namely checking that particular values are being set correctly or that their combination is relevant:

```
[Theory]
public void Person_ValidateState(Person input)
{
    Assume.That(input.Age < 110);
    Assume.That(input.Birth < input.Death || input.Death == null);
    ...
}
```

### Questions

1. Why write unit test theories if one needs to provide enough assumptions for all asserts to pass?
2. If we don't want to *reinvent the wheel* by providing all algorithm assumptions, how do we provide correct assumptions?
3. If that's not the case, how should I rewrite my theory to make it a good example of NUnit theories?
4. What is the intended use (by their creators) of test theories anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Theories vs. parameterized tests

I am also aiming at introducing assumptions in my tests instead of using parameterized tests. But still I haven't started it due to similar thoughts.

The goal of assumptions is to describe the given input as a subset from an uncountable - or say vast but complete - set of values by applying a *filter*. By this your code above is absolutely correct, nevertheless in this case you would have to write several similar tests for negative result testing - eg. when the outcome of `cc.ValidateValue(...)` is `false`. Once again - for comprehensibility - I would still rely on a good choice of hand-picked parameters for a parameterized test of this trivial function.

On the other hand assumptions may be useful for tests of more complex business logic. Imagine you have a garage full of fancy cars and you feel like smashing the gas on some remote terrain - also let's imagine this is a business requirement so you need to write tests for it (how cool would this be!). Then you could write a test like this:

```
[Theory]
public void CarCanDriveOnMuddyGround(Car car)
{
    Assume.That(car.IsFourWheelDrive);
    Assume.That(car.HasMotor);
    Assume.That(car.MaxSpeed > 50);
    Assume.That(car.Color != "white");

    bool result = car.DriveWithGivenSpeedOn<MuddyGround>(50);

    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}
```

See how this is strongly related to the BDD approach? Like you I am also not that much convinced about using assumptions for plain unit tests. But I am certain that it's a good idea to use different approaches for test functions (parameterized, assertions) according to the different test levels (unit, integration, system, user acceptance).

### About algorithm details in assumptions

Thought about your specific problem again. Now I've got your point. In my words: You would need to *assume* that a given value will give a positive result before you can *assert* that it gives a positive result. Right? I think you found a pretty good example why theories do not always work.

I tried to solve it anyway in a slightly simpler example (for readability). But I admit it's not very convincing:

```
public class TheoryTests
{
    [Datapoints]
    public string[] InvalidValues = new[] { null, string.Empty };

    [Datapoints]
    public string[] PositiveValues = new[] { "good" };

    [Datapoints]
    public string[] NegativeValues = new[] { "Bad" };

    private bool FunctionUnderTest(string value)
    {
        return value.ToLower().Equals(value);
    }

    [Theory]
    public void PositiveTest(string value)
    {
        Assume.That(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value));

        var result = FunctionUnderTest(value);

        Assert.True(result);
    }

    [Theory]
    public void PassingPositiveTest(string value)
    {
        Assume.That(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value));
        Assume.That(!NegativeValues.Contains(value));

        var result = FunctionUnderTest(value);

        Assert.True(result);
    }
}
```

`PositiveTest` will fail obviously because the algorithm assumption is missing.
See the second line in the body of `PassingPositiveTest` which prevents the test from failing. The downside is of course that this actually is an *example-based* test and not a pure *theory-based* test. Better ideas welcome.

Comment: I've edited my question to add additional info about theories that only provide assumptions based on input state. That's rather trivial and that's exactly what you provided in your example. But how about theories that have to make assumptions about an algorithm as in my example: validating checksum of given input?

Comment: Ok that's a step forward, but the way you've done it now would be much better by using the usual parametrized test as you'd provide positives and negatives along with expected results. I can't really see where theories fit in?

Comment: That's the point! Both techniques have its pro and contra and for your scenario parameterized tests are more senseful. There's no best solution in my eyes. But if you'd like to go the plain *Theory* way for all tests then this is a valid *workaround* for this problem.

Comment: I'm now in an awkward position. You're the only one to answer my question but I didn't get any valuable answer. Should I reward you the bounty or not? If I accept your answer that means that somebody else would be expecting valuable info there, but they won't.

Comment: I'll take that as a compliment.